# Juno CDT plugin failing to run a C++ application

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a simple mixed C/C++ application (OpenGL example) which I have successfully built using Eclipse CDT in Juno (MinGW toolchain).

I can run this application fine by hand from a Win7 command console, but it seems to rarely work when running from Eclipse's "Run as" menu. Whether it works or not seems down to seemingly unrelated changes in the code, and I get nothing of interest on the Eclipse run console (just a <terminated> status) even when no code near the start of the application has changed.

I'd like to and it sometimes I can work around this for now, but would be good to get this working if anyone has any ideas - it seems an essential stepping stone to get the debug environment working in Eclipse.

*EDIT* Side thought - eclipse seems awfully thin on debug diagnostics when something like this fails. If there is any way to turn on more debug I'd welcome the knowledge =)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - the issue is down to the path being given to the application, or more specifically the OS launcher (so it can find the DLLs it needs).

Even through the default "run" config claims to inherit the parent environment, it doesn't seem to get the same environment as the Win7 command console. I had to manually edit the "Run as" config in Eclipse to have a custom PATH environment variable containing the directories I needed (MinGW/bin, and a directory containing some custom DLLs).

Cheers, Iso